# How to anonymous object works c# entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, object, anonymous

I have a get controller that retrieves all the brands, previously I was using DTO's but found out anonymous objects so I decided to give it a try.

My get method using DTO's was the following:

```
 public async Task < IHttpActionResult > GetBrand(int id) {
     var brand = await db.Brand.Select(x => new {
       brandDesc = x.brandDesc,
       BrandId = x.BrandId,
       brandLogoUrl = x.brandLogoUrl,
       brandName = x.brandName,
       Products = x.Products.Select(y => new {
            productDesc = y.productDesc,
            ProductId = y.ProductId,
            productName = y.productName,
            productPrice = y.productPrice,
            productStock = y.productStock,
            productStatus = y.productStatus,
            productModifyDate = y.productModifyDate
       }).ToList()
     }).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.BrandId == id);
        if (brand == null) {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(brand);
    }
```

My new code with anonymous objects looks like this:

```
public async Task < IHttpActionResult > GetBrand(int id) {
    var brand = await db.Brand.Select(x => new {
        x.brandDesc,
        x.BrandId,
        x.brandLogoUrl,
        x.brandName,
        x.Products
    }).FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.BrandId == id);
    if (brand == null) {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(brand);
}
```

They both return the same output:

```
[{
"brandDesc": "Dicalc phos crys-forearm",
"BrandId": 7,
"brandLogoUrl": "http://dummyimage.com/159x219.png/5fa2dd/ffffff",
"brandName": "ALK-Abello, Inc.",
"Products": [
  {
    "productDesc": "Unspecified umbilical cord complication complicating labor and delivery, antepartum condition or complication",
    "ProductId": 70,
    "productName": "Bigtax",
    "productPrice": 4445.17,
    "productStock": 39,
    "productStatus": true,
    "productModifyDate": "2016-06-03T08:26:24"
  },
  {
    "productDesc": "Adhesions of iris, unspecified",
    "ProductId": 598,
    "productName": "It",
    "productPrice": 1240.36,
    "productStock": 35,
    "productStatus": false,
    "productModifyDate": "2016-06-04T01:00:54"
  }
]
```

}]

Really my question here is how does C# compiler know how to map the  internal object and do not repeat properties, for example in the Brands Class I have a brandID and a Product object, the Product class also has a brandId, when I use DTO's I have to specify manually map the brandId in the Brand DTO and delete that property in the ProductDTO so data is not repeated, but when I use anonymous objects c# internally does this, also the internal object(product) is done in automatic by c#. I'm really surprised that c# could do this without the need to manually specify it

Edit: also found out that I can manually specify a property within the anonymous object:

```
Products = x.Products.Select(y => new {
   productDesc = y.productDesc,
   ProductId = y.ProductId,
   productName = y.productName,
   productPrice = y.productPrice,
   y.productStock,
   y.productStatus,
   y.productModifyDate}).ToList()
```

And specify only the properties that I want

Comment: FYI When you format your code like that it makes it very difficult to read

Comment: I don't think your `Products` class has a `BrandId` property. There's no magic going on here. The compiler is not involved in shaping the result. What you see is nothing but the result of a Json serializer, Json.Net. That too won't remove properties just like that. I'm sure `BrandId` is not there to start with, *or* it's not a public property, *or* it has a JsonIgnore attribute.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic here. The compiler simply creates a hidden class with five properties with identical names and types to the ones you select from the Brand object, and EF instantiates such objects instead of dtos.

Comment: But how does the compiler avoid repeated data? In my brand class I have a brand Id, within the class I have a Product property which also has a brandId, when the compiler creates the anonymous object, the brandId property in the Product object is not created, that really surprised me!!

Comment: You are selecting the products collection with no modification in the 2nd snippet. Something about the product entity itself must prevent the brandid property from being added to the json. This does not have anything to do with anonymous types.